# beautiful soup td class name is same and I need to get the value from 1st to 4th value by text

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, text-parsing, classname

I want to study crawling with selenium and beautiful soup. 
I did successfully accessing the website and logged in.
And I tried to get some value by text but it doesn't work. 
This is the code that I made.

```
all3=soup.find("td",{"class": " text-right txt-r"}).text
print(all3)

all4=soup.find("td",{"class": " text-right txt-r"}).text
print(all4)
```

This is the website coding as follows. I want to get the value from 1st to 4th values by text. However, td class name is same, so I don't know how to get parsing the date with soup.

```
<td class=" text-right txt-r">7,730</td>
<td class=" text-right txt-r">33,500</td>
<td class=" text-right txt-r">72.8</td>
<td class=" text-right txt-r">88</td>
<td class=" text-right txt-r">0.72%</td>
<td class=" text-right txt-r">0.22%</td>
<td class=" text-center txt-c">높음</td>
<td class=" text-right txt-r">15</td>
```

I want to make the result as follows. 
Print(all3)
Print(all4)
Print(all5)
Print(all6)

7,730, 33,500, 72.8, 88

Comment: You can use `find_all` to retrieve all matching elements and then slice the first 4...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But if I change find to find_all, there is an error as follows.

 "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: You have loop over the results and get the `.text` from each element...